# How to warm start with cvxpy using solver SCS

Tags: cvxpy

According to the documentation of cvxpy, http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/advanced/ there should be a way to warm_start SCS solver using cvxpy. (by the way if anyone knows how warm_start can be done using mosek in cvxpy, that would be helpful).

According to this https://github.com/cvxgrp/scs/issues/21  I need the 'x', 'y', and 's' variables. The problem is that I do not know how to get these variables from cvxpy. What do they represent?

My use case is that, I run cvxpy with solver SCS once. Then I change the problem somewhat and i want to solve the problem with a warm_start. However, I don't know how to get the 'x','y' and 's' variables from the first time the problem is solved via cxvpy.

I use:

```
prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, constraints)
prob.solve(solver=cvxpy.SCS)
```

Comment: You probably don't need these in your setting if simple reuse from last iteration is needed and you only replace constants. I explained a bit [here today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263875/cvxpy-how-to-efficiently-solve-a-series-of-similar-problems). Manually, internally something like this is done which should give you the idea: ```scs_args["x"] = solver_cache.prev_result["x"]```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am looking to change the problem somewhat, adding and removing a few variables out of a large problem.