# CVXPY: how to efficiently solve a series of similar problems

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy

I have a large problem defined in [CVXPY modelling language](https://cvxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/intro/index.html). I want to solve series of this problems - still the same format but with different parameters (constants).

I found out that after calling `problem.solve()` internal problem generating takes 20 s and main optimization runtime takes 0.2 s. It's a lot of time when I want to solve dozens of similar problems.

Is there any tool for CVXPY like [YALMIP optimizer](https://yalmip.github.io/command/optimizer/) or any possibility to reduce problem generating time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is. And it's even explained in the official [docs](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html#parameters).

> Parameters
>
> Parameters are symbolic representations of constants. The purpose of parameters is to change the value of a constant in a problem without reconstructing the entire problem.

Example straight from the docs (modified):

```
from cvxpy import *
import numpy

# Problem data.
n = 15
m = 10
numpy.random.seed(1)
A = numpy.random.randn(n, m)
b = numpy.random.randn(n, 1)
# gamma must be positive due to DCP rules.
gamma = Parameter(sign="positive")                       # !!!

# Construct the problem.
x = Variable(m)
error = sum_squares(A*x - b)
obj = Minimize(error + gamma*norm(x, 1))
prob = Problem(obj)                                      # !!!

# Construct a trade-off curve of ||Ax-b||^2 vs. ||x||_1
sq_penalty = []
l1_penalty = []
x_values = []
gamma_vals = numpy.logspace(-4, 6)
for val in gamma_vals:
    gamma.value = val                                    # !!!
    prob.solve()                                         # !!!
    # Use expr.value to get the numerical value of
    # an expression in the problem.
    sq_penalty.append(error.value)
    l1_penalty.append(norm(x, 1).value)
    x_values.append(x.value)
```

#### So what does it do

As you noticed, the setup of your optimization-problem might take some time, because it's following the DCP-approach (which proves convexity by construction).

Using `parameter`, this DCP-processing is only done one time! Every new solve willl only change some small parts within the problem. It's important to describe your parameter as precise as possible, so that DCP can work. Example: `Parameter(sign="positive")`.

#### Is there more you can do

Maybe. Depending on the solver, you can also use **warm-starting**, if you think a special guess (e.g. solution-vector of your last iteration) is a good start for the new problem.

This would replace: `prob.solve()` with `prob.solve(warm_start=True)`, resulting in reusing the previous solution as a start (explained [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#warm-start)). Manually defining this vector does not seem to be possible (from cvxpy).

Sadly, the only solver supporting this (within cvxpy) is SCS as far as i know (and others will ignore it without crashing)!

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much! I didn't know how DCP-processing works. I also try to serialize solved `prob` with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) but unfortunately it raises Exception.

Comment: Interesting. I think i never tried it, but [this reads as this should be possible](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/pull/219), although it's quite old (and a lot of internal changes happened since then, e.g. dropping of cvxopt as requirement).

Comment: "resulting in reusing the previous solution as a start (explained here). " Unfortunately the link is dead, I got a 404 error...

Comment: OSQP also supports warm start.