# Python cvxpy - reuse some constraints

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy

I'm currently using cvxpy to optimize a really big problem but now facing the current issue.
I run multiple iterations of the solver (every iteration reduces the flexibility of some variables).
Every run has 50 constraints in total, of which only 2 of them are different on every run. The remaining 48 constraints are identical.
During every iteration I rebuild from scratch those 2 constraints, the problem, and the obj function.
If I don't rebuild the remaining (same) 48 constraints, the final solution makes no sense.

I read this post [CVXPY: how to efficiently solve a series of similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263875/cvxpy-how-to-efficiently-solve-a-series-of-similar-problems) but here in my case, I don't need to change parameters and re-optimize.

I just managed to prepare an example that shows this issue:

```
    x = cvx.Variable(3)
    y = cvx.Variable(3)

    tc = np.array([1.0, 1.0,1.0])
    constraints2 = [x >= 2]
    constraints3 = [x <= 4]
    constraints4 = [y >= 0]
    
    for i in range(2):
        if i == 0:
            constraints1 = [x - y >= 0]
            
        else:
            x = cvx.Variable(3)
            y = cvx.Variable(3)
            constraints1 = [x + y == 1,
                           x - y >= 1,
                           x - y >= 0,
                           x >= 0]
    
        
        
        constraints = constraints1 + constraints2 + constraints3 + constraints4
        # Form objective.
        obj = cvx.Minimize( (tc.T @ x ) - (tc.T @ y ) )
        
        # Form and solve problem.
        prob = cvx.Problem(obj, constraints)
        prob.solve()
        

        solution_value = prob.value
        solution = str(prob.status).lower() 
        print("\n\n** SOLUTION:  {}     Value: {} ".format(solution, solution_value))
        print("* optimal (x + y == 1) dual variable", constraints[0].dual_value)
        print("optimal (x - y >= 1) dual variable", constraints[1].dual_value)
        print("x - y value:", (x - y).value)
        print("x = {}".format(x.value))
        print("y = {}".format(y.value))
```

As you can see, constraints2 requires all the values in the x vector to be greater than 2.  constraints2 is added in both iterations to "constraints" that is used in the solver.
The second solution should give you values of vector x that are less than 2.
Why? How to avoid this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Why are you redefining the x and y in the for loop? Also, could you elaborate and help me understand what this code snippet illustrates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parameters as described in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263875/cvxpy-how-to-efficiently-solve-a-series-of-similar-problems). Suppose you have the constraint `rhs >= lhs` which is sometimes used and other times not, where `rhs` and `lhs` have dimensions `m x n`. Write the following code:

```
param = cp.Parameter((m, n))
slack = cp.Variable((m, n))
param_constraint = [rhs >= lhs + cp.multiply(param, slack)]
```

Now to turn off the constraint, set `param.values = np.ones((m, n))`. To turn the constraint on, set `param.values = np.zeros((m, n))`. You can turn some entries of the constraint off/on by setting some entries of `param` to be 1 and others to be 0.

Comment: Thank you Steven, I'm just a little concerned what you're referring to refers to values that change over each iterations. In my case above, you can see constraint2 is always the same, nothing really changes. So I dont have any parameters I can iterate on. Would it be possible for you to share a working version of my code above as teaching example? Thanks

Comment: The main issue with your code snippet is that you're redefining x and y, which breaks the code.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, great catch! I spent 3 days on this and that did the job. Thank you Steven!